# Project Euler #2 - Sum of even Fibonacci numbers to 4,000,000

Tags: programming-challenge, clojure, fibonacci-sequence

This particular problem has already been posted here before, but [the community is ok with me to post it again](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/is-it-okay-to-post-the-same-project-euler-solution-using-the-same-language-but), so I can have feedback on my own implementation.

I tried to keep things simple, with each function having its own responsibility so they can be reused in other contexts. Here it is:

```
(ns marcofiset.euler.problem2)

(defn fib [n]
  (if (< n 0)
    (throw (Exception. "Can't compute fib of n < 0"))
    (loop [i n cur 1 next 1]
      (if (zero? i)
        next
        (recur (dec i) next (+ cur next))))))

(defn fibs []
  (map fib (iterate inc 0)))

(defn fibs-until [max]
  (take-while #(< % max) (fibs)))

(defn solution []
  (apply + (filter even? (fibs-until 4000000))))

(println (solution))
```

I'm beginning to learn Clojure and this is one of my first exercices. I'd like to have some feedback from more experienced Clojure programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also kind of a Clojure newbie (I've been messing with it off and on for about two years), so take my comments with a grain of salt.

In the loop in `fib`, I would separate each binding pair with commas, like this:

```
(loop [i n, cur 1, next 1] ; etc.
```

[Clojure treats commas as whitespace](http://clojure.org/reader), so you can use them anywhere you can use a space. It can make binding vectors and map literals with everything on one line a lot easier to read.

It looks like your function `fibs` is just making an infinite lazy sequence of Fibonacci numbers by mapping `fib` over a range. You can actually write a function to do this directly; see http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq (the second example). I don't know how the performance compares, but it's short and a good way to learn about making your own lazy sequences.

I think your solution function is good, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153396/clojure-reduce-vs-apply says there might be a tiny performance advantage to using `reduce` instead, like this:

```
(reduce + (filter even? (fibs-until 4000000)))
```

The hard-coded limit in `solution` makes me uncomfortable somehow. The rest of your code is very nicely packaged out into separate, reusable functions, so it feels a little odd to see `solution` not. Maybe pass the limit as an argument, and then write

```
(println (solution 4000000))
```

Otherwise your code looks good to me. It's very clean and easy to read.

You might also be interested in [type hinting](http://clojure.org/java_interop) and [the `memoize` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/memoize) if you're working through Project Euler; they can help improve performance, especially on mathematical code. For example, if you know the argument to `fib` will always fit in a Java long (64 bits), you can write `fib` like this:

```
(defn fib [^long n]  ;etc
```

This gives the compiler a [type hint](http://clojure.org/java_interop) that lets it avoid reflection, and can improve performance.

You can pass `memoize` a referentially transparent function (one that always returns the same value given the same arguments), and it will return a new version of the function that caches results. For example, say you'd written a naive Fibonacci like this:

```
(defn fib [n]
  (if (< n 2)
    1
    (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

Then you could send that function to `memoize`, and you'd get a new version that would save its previous results. Since that naive function keeps recalculating the same cases, you'd get a performance boost by turning those repeat calls into map lookups.

I hope some of my comments were helpful, and have fun with Clojure; it rekindled my interest in programming.

Comment: Thanks you! A lot of good insight here. Everything you said makes perfect sense.

Comment: @marco-fiset I found advice on idiomatic Clojure a little hard to come by when I started, so I'm glad I could help.